# How to turn off syntax highlighting in console?

Tags: powershell, syntax-highlighting, powershell-5.0, psreadline

I just want PowerShell to be black text on a white background. However, PowerShell v5 highlights my commands and makes them yellow, which is impossible to see. Is there a way to turn off ALL syntax highlighting in PowerShell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Syntax coloring in PowerShell v5 can be modified via [`Set-PSReadlineOption`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt560335.aspx). The following command sets the foregound and background color for comments to the shell foreground and background color:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor -BackgroundColor $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor
```

or just black and white:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor White
```

You need to do this for all `TokenKind` values to remove syntax coloring entirely.

If you also want to change output stream colors you can do that via the properties of the host's [`PrivateData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692799.aspx) object:

```
$Host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
$Host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor = $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor
...
```

Put all of these statements into your [profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) to get them applied every time you start PowerShell, e.g.:

```
$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

Comment: I must say I like the new syntax coloring, but this answer is also useful for customizing it to your individual preferences.

Comment: I fall into situation when I need to display a PS code examples on the projector and projector has an issue - it almost doesn't display a red color. So reading the default color scheme becomes almost impossible.
With this, I reconfigured the color scheme to black and white and that help! Thanks )

Comment: Thanks for this and all of the other answers. It is just nuts that PS doesn't provide an easier way to simply turn off syntax highlighting and use the window's default colors for text and background.

Answer (score 9):

The syntax changed in a recent update. The old syntax will now give you a pesky error message:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Command'.                                                             
At line:1 char:1                                                                
+ Set-PSReadLineOption 'Command' white black                                    
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                    
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PSReadLineOption], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetPSReadLineOption
```

or

```
Set-PSReadLineOption : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name  'TokenKind'.
At line:1 char:22
+ Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor 'black' -Bac ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PSReadLineOption], Par ameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetP SReadLineOption
```

The updated syntax seems to require you to pass in a dictionary of new settings.

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{None='black';Comment='black';Keyword='black';String='black';Operator='black';Variable='black';Command='black';Parameter='black';Type='black';Number='black';Member='black'}
```

If you get

```
Set-PSReadLineOption: 'None' is not a valid color property
```

take out the `None='black';`, like this:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{Comment='black';Keyword='black';String='black';Operator='black';Variable='black';Command='black';Parameter='black';Type='black';Number='black';Member='black'}
```

See also https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/738

Comment: Set-PSReadLineOption: 'None' is not a valid color property ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I guess it changed again? Fortunately, I no longer have a Windows environment where I can troubleshoot that. Try taking out the `None='black';` from inside the `@{...}`

Comment: That's what I did.  But perhaps I should have added that I'm trying this with Powershell on Linux.

Comment: I didn't understand from your comment that that fixed it, but I have worked it out and added an update. Thanks for prodding me, but perhaps work on providing more context in your comments. At your reputation level, I believe you should be eligible to submit an edit suggestion to improve this answer, too.

Comment: In case others need it going forward, `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest` gets you a Debian image with Powershell. Installing it yourself in a Docker image is problematic because the various installation scripts I could find require `systemd` which you don't get out of the box with stock Docker images for Debian. The source for this image is https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker

Comment: Got the `Set-PSReadLineOption: 'None' is not a valid color property` message (SSH session to a `Windows Server 2022` using Teraterm on Windows), taking out the `None='black';` from inside the `@{...}` worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Frant Thanks - updated to remove the parenthetical which suggested this was a Linux problem.

Answer (score 7):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--set-multiple-color-options

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
  Command            = 'White'
  Number             = 'White'
  Member             = 'White'
  Operator           = 'White'
  Type               = 'White'
  Variable           = 'White'
  Parameter          = 'White'
  ContinuationPrompt = 'White'
  Default            = 'White'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Example, how to turn off all syntax highlighting:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Operator -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Type -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Variable -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Number -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Member -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Keyword -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -ContinuationPromptForegroundColor DarkYellow -ContinuationPromptBackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -EmphasisForegroundColor DarkYellow -EmphasisBackgroundColor DarkMagenta
Set-PSReadlineOption -ErrorForegroundColor DarkYellow -ErrorBackgroundColor DarkMagenta

(Get-Host).PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor="DarkYellow"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor="DarkYellow"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor="DarkYellow"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor="DarkYellow"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor="DarkYellow"
(Get-Host).PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
```

[See screenshot (Windows10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fWwA.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
get-help set-psreadlineoption
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption

```
'None', 'Comment', 'Keyword', 'String', 'Operator', 
'Variable', 'Command', 'Parameter', 'Type', 'Number', 'Member' |
foreach { set-psreadlineoption $_  black white }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing it in osx for the things that immediately bother me:

```
$a = get-psreadlineoption | select ErrorBackgroundColor
$clear = $a.ErrorBackgroundColor

'command','number','operator','member' |
foreach { set-psreadlineoption $_ black $clear }
```

Comment: Which operating system you are connecting to Windows from should hardly matter, should it?