# Positional Parameter error in powershell script

Tags: powershell, positional-parameter

I was trying to install/update EPO agent through PowerShell, but I am getting below error. 
I am new to PowerShell so I am not able to see what is causing this.

Below is the script I used to update the agent :

```
Start-Process -FilePath $scriptpath "\INAEPO01_Framepkg.exe" "/FORCEINSTALL" "/INSTALL=AGENT" -Wait
```

Error :

> Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
>   /FORCEINSTALL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it like that, i.e. add commas between the arguments so that they form an array

```
Start-Process -FilePath $scriptpath "\INAEPO01_Framepkg.exe","/FORCEINSTALL", "/INSTALL=AGENT" -Wait
```

or to be more explicit

```
Start-Process -FilePath $scriptpath -ArgumentList "\INAEPO01_Framepkg.exe", "/FORCEINSTALL", "/INSTALL=AGENT" -Wait
```

Comment: Comma to the rescue!