# Start-Process powershell.exe with an argument

Tags: windows, powershell, vim

How do I start a new powershell instance and tell that instance to execute a certain command?

What I've tried:

(Assuming `vim.exe` and `file.txt` is in cwd)

`Start-Process powershell.exe .\vim.exe .\file.txt`

`vim.exe` is the parameter to `powershell.exe`

`file.txt` is the parameter to `vim.exe`

Error says:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'.\file.txt'.At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe .\vim.exe .\file.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I've also tried `powershell.exe -ArgumentList {.\vim.exe .\file.txt}` and no dice.

Comment: `Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ".\vim.exe .\file.txt"`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 hmmm, it started without with an error and instantly quit. `-noexit` isn't working either so I can't see the error

Comment: no idea, works fine for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positional Parameter error in powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407004/positional-parameter-error-in-powershell-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Argument list is an array... say `start-process` doesn't know what to do with `.\file.txt`

Here is how I would write it

```
 Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList @('.\vim.exe', '.\file.txt')
```

The following will also work, but I like the above where you explicitly say you want an array

```
 Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '.\vim.exe', '.\file.txt'
```