# Start - Process : A position parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell, microfocus

I'm getting the above error when trying to run from powershell.

```
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SafeNet Sentinel\Sentinel RMS License Manager\WinNT\cesadmintool" -term install -f FileName
```

Comment: You cut off the error message at the crucial point and your command line is not Powershell. It's cmd.Please read the help for [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1) completely incl. the examples and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even I tried with cmd. It is not specifying any issues but unable to install license files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions? You could read the help I linked in my comment above and use the cmdlet like the inventors planned it to be used.  ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positional Parameter error in powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407004/positional-parameter-error-in-powershell-script)

Answer (score 3):

Your command is not correct.

In PowerShell, `start` is an alias for the `Start-Process` cmdlet. PowerShell does not use parameters that start with `/`, so it has no `/wait` parameter. You are trying to use the `start` command that's built into `cmd.exe` in PowerShell. That does not work, as you have noticed.

This is all you need to do in PowerShell:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\SafeNet Sentinel\Sentinel RMS License Manager\WinNT\cesadmintool" -term install -f FileName
```

(Presumably you need to replace the word "FileName" with some actual file's name.)

The `&` at the beginning of the line is PowerShell's call (invocation) operator. It lets you run a string as a command.